# Get right Pipewire object with object id

Tags: awk, pipewire

I need to know Pipewire object.serial that corresponds to a specific object.

Parsing output of `pw-cli list-objects` is what I need, but I'm very poor with multiline regex.

`pw-cli list-objects` gives this:

```
id 0, type PipeWire:Interface:Core/4
    object.serial = "0"
    core.name = "pipewire-0"
id 1, type PipeWire:Interface:Module/3
    object.serial = "1"
    module.name = "libpipewire-module-rt"
id 2, type PipeWire:Interface:Module/3
    object.serial = "2"
    module.name = "libpipewire"
...
...
```

I don't know, what is the name of this format, so I need to parse it myself.

I need to first recognize objects (id 1,2,...), then put them one-by-one to line-by-line regex, select right object and then parse right parameter with regex.

How can I detect objects with AWK?

1. Detect objects with multiline regex pattern
2. Put objects one-by-one through line-by-line regex pattern e.g. with grep and select right object
3. I'm in a situation where awk pushes right object and then I parse right value of the right parameter
   For example: `grep -G "\s.*object.serial = \".*\"" | cut -d '"' -f`

---

For @marcus-müller

Okay, so my goal is manipulate audio of the certain process.

I have way in my script to get surely know right PID for the process. Pipewire doesn't understand PIDs, so I have to get know correponding `object.serial` for that PID. However, it graph include them and save them to `pipewire.sec.pid` parameter. With that parameter I can recognise the right object from the graph and then use other parameters of it, among others `object.serial`.

Proof that Pipewire server know PIDs for its clients:

1. Run `pw-play [path to a audio file] &`, `cvlc [path to a audio file] &` or something other player. The goal is start playing audio and know PID for that process. Note: the file needs to be long enough so you have time to run the following commands.
2. Run `pw-cli ls | grep [the pid]` and that will return `pipewire.sec.pid = "[PID]"`. That proofs that the graph of Pipewire server knows PIDs. If you run `pw-cli ls | grep -B20 -A20 [the pid]` you will see to what object that parameter belongs.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: These `id`s are **not** PIDs! Took me a while to understand what you want... Proposing a fix to your question...

Comment: @ConstantineA.B. I know, but parameters of those objects contain it. So, I want detect object and put them through grep one-by-one, grep search object with certain PID, when right object is found put whole object through `grep -G "\s.*object.serial = \".*\"" | cut -d '"' -f´` and now I have corresponding object.serial for the PID. The problem is I'm poor with multiline patterns... I think AWK is best for this, but I don't know how use it.

Comment: @Basher these are really not PIDs, stop calling them that.

Comment: What makes you think Pipewire server wouldn't know PIDs for *its own clients*? Test yourself :) First run `pw-play &` and bash will tell you PID, then `pw-cli ls|grep -B10 [PID]` and now you see the object corresponding that PID.

Comment: Please note that output of `pw-cli list-objects` in the topic is just snip. It shows an example of a pattern that I need to recognize. The entire output has more parameters such as PID.

Comment: Maybe someone knows name for that pattern? I haven't seen it before, but it seems *a bit* similar with YAML.

Comment: @Basher Pipewire does indeed **not** know the PIDs of most objects that it tracks, *by design*, especially considering Pipewire's design was meant for *portals* that connect and then hand the connection to another process. Plus, there's not a single `pipewire.sec.pid` line in the output you show, so really, you are *not* asking about PIDs, or you're asking for something that pipewire will have a hard time telling you :) `object.serial` is *not* a PID, and that seems to be the only thing you're looking at.

Comment: Of course it doesn't know PID for every object, but for programs it does. Do you test my commands? To me it shows `pipewire.sec.pid` and then I can identify right object for the PID. All other parameters like `application.name` proof that the object is right. I will now update my question with more spesific details and then you maybe understand.

Comment: You describe how you think you want to approach your problem, but you don't tell us what the actual problem is you're trying to solve. You want to do something with some block of lines based on some criteria but what criteria? Is it something to do with some value associated with the `object.serial` tag (it looks like it might be from the `grep` command you posted)? Please [edit] your question to state WHAT you need to do (as opposed to HOW you're trying to do it with a multi-line regexp), and show the expected output given your posted sample input.